# How to recover broken MJPEG AVI file after a camera crash

Tags: linux, video, window, video-conversion, video-capture

I was recording a video when my KODAK EASYSHARE M531 Digital Camera fell to the ground and turned off. When i turned it on nothing happened to the camera but the video file is somehow broken. Obviously the camera did not have time to convert and close it properly.

```
$file myvid.avi
myvid.AVI: data
```

where it should be:

```
another_vid.AVI: RIFF (little-endian) data, AVI, 640 x 480, ~30 fps, video: Motion JPEG, audio: uLaw (stereo, 12000 Hz)`
```

I would like to fix my video which I believe needs to be converted to AVI. Any idea?

---

VLC does not play the file and returns:

> could not determine type of stream

Comment: What kind of a camera?

Comment: I'm struggling to see what you're meaning after the first paragraph. Is myvid.avi the filename that's stored on your camera's memory stick or something?

Comment: @choroba `KODAK EASYSHARE M531 Digital Camera`

Comment: @HenningKlevjer myvid.avi is the file that stored on both memcard and copied to my hdd, also it is the file i am looking to fix

Comment: And it doesn't play? What error do you get when attempting playback?

Comment: @HaydnWVN no it is not working, the error is `could not determine type of stream`

Comment: Is there a chance you can supply the broken file to us?

Comment: @slhck i wish i can supply the file but unfortunately it is private

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to access the file, try opening it with the [VideoLan player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html).  If that doesn't play, you're probably going to need some sort of forensics expert to recover the video.

Comment: it did not work with VLC or mplayer :(

Comment: Try a piece of software called 'virtual dub', I've not used it for many years but previously converted strange RAW mobile formats to working 'Windows' formats.